# What methods can solve SOCP problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

What methods can solve SOCP problems?

I need at least few different.

By:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming

it seems that the problem "reduces" to simpler problems, but I'm not sure as to what should determine what kind of algorithms are usable.

Comment: interior point methods are the reason SOCP got so popular